# sharing code on Answers.ros.org

Tags: ros, answers.ros.org

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When people correspond on this site and they want to share code back and forth as well as with the greater audience following a topic or conversation that interests them, is there a common location or way to share the code?
Thanks, -Scott

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9271/sharing-code-on-answers.ros.org/) by [Scott](https://answers.ros.org/users/100/scott/) on ROS Answers with karma: 693 on 2011-03-03

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Small snippits can be inlined.

Larger snippits or whole files can be posted on places like [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/)

If you want to share a larger chunk of code I would suggest hosting it properly in a version control system which is public.  There are many such as <del>[googlecode](http://code.google.com/)</del> [sourceforge](http://sf.net) [github](http://github.com) and [bitbucket](http://bitbucket.org) to name a few ones with free service.

**Update:**

Google Code is no longer active

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-03-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on 2011-03-03**:
I would second Tully's suggestion to use a shared version control system.  I've been using GoogleCode's svn system but only as a single user so I don't know how well it works with multiple authors.  The process seems to be that one person sets up a repository and then sends a password to others giving them permission to check stuff back in.  (Checking out is public.)  I see others are using git or mercurial so there may be better reasons to go that way.  But for example, Scott could set up a GoogleCode repository called something like "facedetect-ros-pkg" and we can start plugging away at some code.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I personally prefer http://ideone.com/

it's an online compiler and debugging tool which allows to compile and run code online in more than 40 programming languages.

---

Originally posted by [blueskin](https://answers.ros.org/users/26/blueskin/) with karma: 284 on 2011-03-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1